# How can we display the temporary column name (which is not present in the table) ONLY, when using the case statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How does one display the temporary column name (which is not present in the table) ONLY, when using the case statement?
For example:

```
select my_column_name,
case 
when X <=10 then 'A'
when X >=11 AND X <=19 then 'B'
when X >=20 then 'C'
else 'Some error occured'
END AS my_column_name
from  table_name
```

now if I execute this MySql workbench gives this error:

**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'my_column_name' in 'field list'**

this will work if I give column names which are in the table or just give the * but it does not work if I just want the temporary name/alias (I'm not sure what this column is called)

Comment: You don't need to select `my_column_name` twice: you just need `select case ... END AS my_column_name from table_name`.

Comment: You should consider to make your condition more explicit that tells some error has occured. It's bad to read since you need to check all previous conditions when it's just an else clause. So I would write a first when before the 3 other when's and then remove the else part. The first when will be "when (x>10 and x<11) or (x>19 and x<20) then 'Some error occured'"

Comment: @JonasMetzler I know, that part was irrelevant so I didn't give it much detailing, I just came up with a quick code to explain the problem statement, the main question was how to display the column name which "lemon" has already answered.